# Want to create Oauth client in falcon

Tags: python, falcon

I want to create a oauth client which will only authenticate token and this should in falcon python i am new to oauth please share

to authenticate token which is on cloud server and falcon is running on my machine and Java application is sending a request in j son format string with oauth token in it i just want to validate on my cloud server